# Meaning or Grammatical Function of かき

Tags: questions

I've been transcribing this video.

https://youtu.be/ZoGKmPJkVr4

At 7:33, there's this sentence,

"犬かきならぬ、ネコかき。"

I wonder what かき means here, or if it serves some grammatical function? Thank you!

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/inukaki I know you already know that 犬かき is in the video, but looking at the entry for it should answer your question.

Comment: oh right! thank you! it didn't occur to me that it came together with 犬!!

Comment: @mouldyfart wow what a username!

Answer (score 1):

This かき is a nominalized form of the verb [掻く【かく】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/38483/meaning/m0u/%E6%8E%BB%E3%81%8F/), which means "to scratch", "to paw", "to paddle (in the water)", "to plow (snow)", etc. 犬かき refers to a certain swimming method, and 猫かき is a parody of it (i.e., the word 猫かき is basically a joke).